# Python + eyeD3: cannot save date to mp3 metadata

Tags: python, date, tags, mp3, metadata

I am trying to update metadata of a bunch of mp3 files using Python and its eyeD3 API.

It looks fairly simple, code I'm using looks as follows:

```
if not eyeD3.isMp3File(filename):
    print filename, 'is not a mp3 file. Ignoring it.'
tag = eyeD3.Tag()
tag.link(filename)
tag.setVersion(eyeD3.ID3_V2)
tag.setTextEncoding(eyeD3.UTF_8_ENCODING)
tag.setTitle(dataset['Title'])
tag.setDate(datetime.datetime.now().year)
tag.update()
```

What happens is: code executes silently (no errors or exceptions), title is set correctly, date is **not** set in target file. It remains empty or set to previous value (checked both cases).

Help for setDate function is not particulary amusing:

```
setDate(self, year, month=None, dayOfMonth=None, hour=None, minute=None, second=None, fid=None) unbound eyeD3.tag.Tag method
```

... but tells me that my call should be ok. Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: Having glanced over the sourcecode, I don't see anything obviously wrong.

Comment: Found out that command line eyeD3 does exactly the same: doesn't change date, but doesn't report any error either. Having a deadline coming, I used Mutagen for this purpose. I guess we just have a bug in eyeD3 somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same question as yours. Finally, I abandoned the eyeD3 lib, `mutagen` is a good option.

Here is my example using `mutagen.mp3` in Python.

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
from mutagen.id3 import ID3, APIC, TIT2, TPE1, TRCK, TALB, USLT, error
# ID3 info:
# APIC: picture
# TIT2: title
# TPE1: artist
# TRCK: track number
# TALB: album
# USLT: lyric
def id3_cook(directory, filename, item, track_num):
    pic_file = directory + '/cover.jpg' # pic file
    audio = MP3(filename, ID3=ID3)
    try:
        audio.add_tags()
    except:
        pass
    audio.tags.add(APIC(
        encoding=3,
        mime='image/jpeg',
        type=3,
        desc=u'Cover Picture',
        data=open(pic_file).read()
    ))
    audio.tags.add(TIT2(encoding=3, text=item['song'].decode('utf-8')))
    audio.tags.add(TALB(encoding=3, text=item['album'].decode('utf-8')))
    audio.tags.add(TPE1(encoding=3, text=item['artist'].decode('utf-8')))
    audio.tags.add(TRCK(encoding=3, text=str(track_num).decode('utf-8')))
    audio.tags.add(USLT(encoding=3, lang=u'eng', desc=u'desc', text=item['lyric'].decode('utf-8')))
    audio.save()
```